# how to run external javascript file from v8 shell?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm looking for a method to run external javascript frm v8 shell.

For running a javascript in v8 shell, the whole script should be in a one line. Otherwise v8 shell gives syntax errors in the javascript.

What I can do to run bit of large javascript code from v8 shell?

I have successfully run javascripts from the consolse.It works fine.When it comes to run bit of large javascript codes v8 gives sysntax errors but when I removed new lines it worked.I just want to know is there a way to run javascript from external file.

```
function strAdd1()
{
    var start = new Date().valueOf();
    var str = "This is the string that will be tested. it is a long one with numbers 1234567890";
    for(var i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        str += "This is the string that will be tested. it is a long one with numbers 1234567890";
    }
    return new Date().valueOf() - start;
}
```

Comment: BTW, have you tried anything on your end?

Comment: I have successfully run javascripts from the consolse.It works fine.When it comes to run bit of large javascript codes v8 gives sysntax errors but when I removed new lines it worked.I just want to know is there a way to run javascript from external file.

Comment: you need to add the code that you have tried. It makes easy for fellow members to understand your requirement easily, And it is better to show your code and get it corrected rather than asking fellow members to write code from scratch. I have edited your question to reflect more readability, meanwhile  you add the relevant code that you have tried.

Comment: No need to provide realtime code. Just a sample code would do.

Comment: Sorry about not adding the code.Since this is my first question the suggestions you gave is really helpful me to improve the quality of the problem.I have   tried this code                         `function strAdd1(){
    var start = new Date().valueOf();
    var str = "This is the string that will be tested. it is a long one with numbers 1234567890";
    for(var i=0;i<100000;i++){
        str += "This is the string that will be tested. it is a long one with numbers 1234567890";
    }
    return new Date().valueOf() - start;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `How to load external javascript file from v8 shell` ?

Then, use `load`.

**foo.js**

```
print("hello world");
```

call `load()`

```
> load("foo.js")
```

However, this is a function for just only v8 shell. so if you want to use generally way on javascript, you should improve v8 shell.

Comment: yes.I meant that.Thank you very much for the feedback.I tried the way you specify and I had able to do load the external javascript file.